# what is the difference between sync and async input source for run loops?

Tags: ios, foundation

What does it mean that input sources such as port deliver events to a run loop async while timers deliver events synchronously.

Does the timer block the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Threading Programming Guide: Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) says:

> A run loop receives events from two different types of sources. *Input sources* deliver asynchronous events, usually messages from another thread or from a different application. *Timer sources* deliver synchronous events, occurring at a scheduled time or repeating interval. Both types of source use an application-specific handler routine to process the event when it arrives.

But a timer only blocks the thread while the timer’s closure or selector method is running. But as soon as you return from that, the thread is no longer blocked. So make sure to get in and out as quickly as possible.

For example, if you have scheduled a timer to fire in 10 seconds, and the code in the timer’s handling closure/selector takes 100 msec to run, then the thread is not blocked until the timer fires, and then only for 100 msec. Same with repeating timers.

Bottom line, as long as you’re not doing anything too computationally expensive in your timer handler, there’s nothing to worry about. And if you do need to do anything that might block for any material amount of time, then either have your timer handler asynchronously dispatch that relevant code to some background queue, or just schedule a GCD timer to run on a background queue directly, bypassing `Timer` altogether.

But for most `Timer` use-cases, this just isn’t an issue.

Comment: Thanks that was spot on , as for async handlers for custom inputs such as selectors , do they get rescheduled to a later run loop ?

Comment: The whole idea of completion handlers (whether blocks or selectors) is that they're asynchronous, non-blocking by definition, not invoked until the relevant event takes place. Whether they're processed by a runloop or GCD will vary, but is an implementation detail that we generally don't worry about. We use these asynchronous patterns precisely to avoid blocking.